# jfrog-artifactory docker image - halting due to nofile usage

Tags: docker-compose, artifactory

I have a docker-compose topology with jenkins-gitlab-artifactory,and i am using the jfrog-artifactoey docker image from jfrog :
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker

here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services: 

    jenkins:
        container_name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes: 
            - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

    artifactory:
        container_name: artifactory
        image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:6.16.0
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        volumes: 
            - artifactory_data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
        ulimits:
            nproc: 65535
            nofile:
                soft: 32000
                hard: 40000
volumes: 

    jenkins_home:
    artifactory_data:
```

At first i got an error `ERROR: Max number of open files 1024, is too low. Cannot run Artifactory!`

After setting the ulimit in docker compose the container is up and running , but the artifactory container is exiting with the following log :

`/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactory.sh: line 185:   230 Killed                  $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run`

Comment: Please share some more log output.

Comment: @galusben while following the container logs it looks like the initialization is OK , at some point the computer is getting slow and lagging , and the container is exited with the log iv'e mentioned. running on a different machine the container is fully functioning(with ulimit set) , could this be OS version related?(both Linux ubuntu)

Comment: Maybe resources issue on the host, like memory or disk space.